# Using contains logic in APEX using URL variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, parameters

I am a rookie when it comes to APEX, but here goes...We have a form which outputs a URL parameter on a new VF page containing a major.  This is supposed to display any orientations available for that major.  The field that contains this is a text field and can contain more than one major, separated by comma (but can be changed to another character if needed).

The following code is part of the controller that will display all orientations.  This works to display any that equal the exact major, but not any that include the major value with others. (ie 'Nursing, Biology')

```
public string urlParams                         {get; set;}
String myMajor = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('maj');
String myContact = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cont');

public ApexPages.StandardSetController setORIENTATION_event {
    get {
        if(setORIENTATION_event == null) {
            setORIENTATION_event = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                     [SELECT c.ID, c.Name, c.TargetX_Eventsb__Description__c,
 c.TargetX_Eventsb__Start_Time_TZ_Adjusted__c,
 c.TargetX_Eventsb__End_Time_TZ_Adjusted__c,
 c.TargetX_Eventsb__Event_Cost__c, c.TargetX_Eventsb__Map_URL__c,
 c.TargetX_Eventsb__Map_URL_Text__c,
 c.TargetX_Eventsb__Slots_Available__c FROM
 TargetX_Eventsb__OrgEvent__c c WHERE
 c.TargetX_Eventsb__Slots_Available__c'0' AND
 c.TargetX_Eventsb__Type__c='Orientation' AND
 c.TargetX_Eventsb__custom_field_10_label__c LIKE :myMajor])); // THIS LINE
```

I have tried searching for a solution on here and dev forums, have tried different code options, but cannot get this to work with multiple values.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean multiple values?

Comment: @Adrian-Larson, what I meant was the source record could have multiple values in a single field comma separated (ie "Theatre, Dance, Arts")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `maj` parameter is exactly one major, you can modify your soql query to include the `%` wildcard:

```
c.TargetX_Eventsb__custom_field_10_label__c LIKE :('%' + myMajor + '%')
```

That said, this opens up the possibility of selecting false positives, e.g. if `maj` is "Engineering" and an event has the major "Computer Engineering".  Assuming your data is formated exactly as `value1, value2, value3` (and no majors contain unescaped commas), you could test against each case explicitly in SOQL:

```
c.TargetX_Eventsb__custom_field_10_label__c = :myMajor OR
c.TargetX_Eventsb__custom_field_10_label__c LIKE :(myMajor + ',%') OR
c.TargetX_Eventsb__custom_field_10_label__c LIKE :('%, ' + myMajor + ',%') OR
c.TargetX_Eventsb__custom_field_10_label__c LIKE :('%, ' + myMajor)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to split the `maj` value on your delimiter and then use the `IN` operator rather than the `LIKE` operator.

```
String myMajor = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('maj');

// an array / list to be used by the query
List<String> myMajorsList = new List<String>();

// only do the work if we have a value from the query param to split
if (myMajor != null) {
    myMajorsList = myMajor.split(','); // regex split on the comma
}
```

... then your query could use the list of values

```
c.TargetX_Eventsb__Type__c = 'Orientation' AND
c.TargetX_Eventsb__custom_field_10_label__c IN :myMajorsList]
```

Comment: Thanks Mark!  I went with Brian's answer but I have another use for your solution.